# How do I deploy my app which uses auth0 with next js? It asks me to use generateStaticParams

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0, generatestaticparams

I'm trying to deploy an app with `react/nextjs` as I used to with `create-react-app` which builds the files to upload to the server and run the website. (I'm using a shared php server and I have no choice but to use this one).

Now, I'm reading that to build a static website (actually I am not sure if this is what I need) I have to have `output:"export"` in `next.config.mjs` file but when I do so, I get the following error at build:

```
Error: Page "/api/auth/[auth0]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
```

In this directory, based on tutorials I have a file called `route.js` with the following content:

```
import { handleAuth } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
export const GET = handleAuth();
```

The login of the website is built using `auth0`. I would be glad to get some help to know where or how to use `generateStaticParams()` or if I'm doing it in a wrong way.